# User creation with limited access

Tags: 20.04, user-management, chroot, administration, adduser

How to create a user with access to selected applications installed in the system and read/write permission to only one directory in the file system?

Say, for example, one wants to create a user `dummy` with read and write access to only the directory `/home/dummy` and nowhere else. Also, `dummy` would be able to use the `firefox` browser and a `TeX` application like `kile` or `texstudio`, and no other applications installed on the system is accessible to `dummy`. Can this be achieved?

If it is not possible for the applications, can the part of restricting directory be done?

**Update**

The least property needed:
`/home/user1` can't read `/home/user2`
By default user creation read access is not restricted.

Comment: Which applications?

Comment: A web browser and TeX application like kile or texstudio

Comment: You can do this, but you probably don't want to. Most operating system functions (listing files, checking for wifi APs) rely on binaries or libraries in `/usr/bin` or `/lib` and on configuration files in `/etc`. If you deny read access to those things, those functions will break. Ditto programs like a browser or kile and texstudio. You'll spend ages debugging which specific files you **need** to grant access to to have your programs work. What are you actually trying to achieve? Why shouldn't a user _read_ system binaries and config files and stuff, since they can't write outside `/home/user`?

Comment: @Dan Scally `/home/user1` is able to read `/home/user2` with default user creation. At least can this be restricted?

Comment: Sure, you can just restrict "Other" permissions to those directories with `chmod o-rwx /home/userX` - that means "Remove Read, Write and Execute permissions to /home/userX directory for anyone other than the Owner and Group owner of the directory"

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, but you probably don't want to. Most operating system functions (listing files, checking for wifi APs) rely on binaries or libraries in /usr/bin or /lib and on configuration files in /etc. If you deny read access to those things, those functions will break. Ditto programs like a browser or kile and texstudio. You'll spend ages debugging which specific files you need to grant access to to have your programs work.

If you just want to deny a user access to any other User's home directory, you can simply run `chmod o-rwx /home/username`, which basically means *remove read, write and execute permissions to the /home/username for all users except the owner (or users in the file group)*. If you just want it to be the owner and not the file group, use `u-rwx`